# Save and load workspace in app on local server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app running on a local server, accessible through the web browser via 'ip-adres:port'. I have a task scheduled in task planner that executes the following code (path: "C://Users//Administrator//Documents//run.R"

```
require(shiny)
folder_address = "C://Users//Administrator//Documents//App//app.R"

x <- system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE)
z <- x[grep("IPv4", x)]
ip <- gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", z)

runApp(folder_address, launch.browser = FALSE, port = 1234, host = ip)
```

The task is executing just fine, since I am able to access the app through 'ip:port'.

At the start of `app.R` I manually load the workspace: `load("C://Users//Administrator//Documents//App//.RData")`.
When I don't load it manually, the app won't recognize variables/dataframes of the app.

My problem is as followed:

- The task is scheduled to run every morning. When we only run the task once, it might happen that the server has an update or so and restarts. That way, the app is no longer running.
- When the task is is running the next day after edits have been made in the app (that is, variables and dataframes have been changed), it loads the workspace again.
- This workspace does not contain the edited data, since the workspace does not save automatically after edits.
- When I manually put `save.image(".RData")` in `app.R` on events that trigger data edits, such as buttons, it saves the workspace of `run.R`, leaving me with the variables `x`, `z`, `ip` and `folder_address`.

How can I save the workspace of the app, rather than the workspace of `run.R`? A workaround would be to net let the task run every day and just let it open. But then we would have to manually rerun the task once it stops bacause of an update for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of getting the result you want.

Two of the best ways of [persisting data](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) are to use a database or to store objects in a service like Amazon S3.

If you must save the R environment, could you adapt your app to save after every edit, so that if it does get interrupted, it starts again at the same spot the next morning?

Alternatively, could you refactor your app to save `rds` files (r files) and read them in when the app starts, and save each one after an edit (this could be much faster than saving the whole R environment)

Comment: Decided to save dataframes as a csv after edits and open those csv's at the start of the app. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: No worries. Just a small tip; `csv` files will probably be okay 99% of the time, but every now and again something will trip up the functions R uses to read csvs. So I would suggest using `saveRDS` and `readRDS` instead (these simply save/read R objects instead of csvs). Other advantages are that these are typically much more memory efficient (and therefore faster) and you can not only save dataframes but any R objects you like!

Comment: Have not worked with rds files before, but will try it out and see if that works as well, thank you!